# How do I get a 100 most recent Outlook emails using VBScript from a profile that uses Cached Exchange Mode?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a piece of script that grabs the 100 most recent received emails from an Outlook inbox. It works fine in an Outlook profile that doesn't use Cached Exchange Mode, giving us the most recent 100 emails. However if the Outlook profile has Cached Exchange Mode enabled I get a block of 100 emails from a seemingly random point in time two years ago.

```
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application, olNs As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim i As Long

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFolder = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set myItems = olFolder.Items
myItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True

For i = 1 To 100
    If TypeOf myItems(i) Is MailItem Then
        Set olMail = myItems(i)
        ...
        ' do something with each email
        ...
    End If
Next i
```

Is there a better way to do this that will get the 100 most recent emails whether Cached Exchange Mode is enabled or not?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way other than forcing the user to change how far back in time the user is caching their Outlook data.  Think of it this way: the user has told Outlook they only want the last months worth of data to work with.  To the extent and purposes of custom applications, this is ALL they get to interact with.  A custom app should only assume the data they can access is all there is and no more.  The rest is up to the user to open up for other apps to access.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but forgive me, I'm a little confused. Maybe I didn't explain this very well. Their mailbox shows three or four years worth of emails. And what I want to access is always the 100 most recent emails. But the script is returning a random block of 100 emails from 2015. I assume it is something to do with what is stored in the PST file versus the OST file. Like Outlook is only replying with content from the PST file perhaps.

Comment: Okay, I understand. I can't explain the behaviour you're seeing; AFAIK it should return the latest available items when you sort it by date descending. BTW, there is no correlation between a pst file and an ost; the latter is never used for an Exchange account (unless it is a delivery folder, which is unusual).

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using EWS instead. See [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information. In that case you will not get unpredictable results depending on the time when users synced with the server to get the latest.

Comment: But the problem isn't that we're getting slightly out of date emails. The problem is that all we're getting is emails from two years ago. The user in this case syncs their mailbox a little more often than every two years.